# PHP working with milliseconds

Tags: php

I have the following value (generated as GMT Time) being retrieved from an API call

```
Song Started Time : 2017-09-06T16:51:02.000Z
```

I also have the duration (in form of milliseconds) of a specific song tied to that record in the API response. For example, it may return:

```
222000
```

Then, using PHP GMT time function I'm checking what the current time is on a PHP page.

```
World Current Time: 2017-09-06T16:51:31.000Z
```

Using PHP, how would I be able to determine how far along in the song I currently am, using the start time, fixed duration of the song, and the current time. I figure this should be fairly simple, but I'm struggling to figure out how to add milliseconds in PHP. Ideally, the output I'm looking for should just say .33 to indicate the song is currently 33% completed.

Comment: what is the logic behind 33%? how you come to know based on those threee values which you mentioned?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: The 33% was hypothetical. Essentially, I know what time the song started playing, and I know how long it is. At any given point in time I should be ably to figure out how far along in the song it is based on what the current time is. Primitive, I know, but this API is funky.

Comment: considering most songs are around the 3:30 minute mark, wouldn't it be simler to use seconds instead?

Comment: While this is true, for some reason the API only returns song length in the format of milliseconds. Although yes, I could just easily convert that to regular seconds and go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to find song played time in percent

```
  <?php
      $date = new DateTime("2017-09-06T16:51:02.000Z");
      $date2 = new DateTime("2017-09-06T16:51:31.000Z");
      $interval = $date2->diff($date)->s;
      $duration = 222;//222000/1000 to make milliseconds in seconds
      echo $song_played = (int)(($interval/$duration)*100) . "%";
  ?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/856523

Example you gave is for `13%` not for `33%`

Comment: This is working great. If I may, one additional question. I am putting the variable $startedTime (which is received back from the API call) inside DateTime, like this:   $date = new DateTime($startedTime); but it does not seem to recognize that when doing the calculation and just returns 0%

Comment: Looking at error log I am seeing "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string"

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. Forgot to close a quotation mark elsewhere in code. Thanks for the help it all works great now!